# SharePoint 2010 - Three-State ootb Workflow with multiple user for a step?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server

I want to use the three state out of the box workflow in SharePoint 2010. My problem is now, that I only can assign a task to one user for a step (It is not possible to add a second person in this field)

Is there any way to assign a task to a group?

p/s: I can't use any other software such as InfoPath or SPD.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge that multiple users are not allowed for the field. If you have no access to SPD I am not sure if you have other options. I tested with custom AD groups and it does not get resolved. You can have a try with it.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

You can only assign the task to a specific person in this field. Per my test, groups are not allowed in this field as it.

Here is an article for you about valid values can be typed in when creating an OOB 3-state workflow:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-a-three-state-workflow-bb91586e-99a2-4cf7-b810-998b5120a6e0#bm3

Comment: Thank you for your explanation :)